# Как узнать что завершился процесс, вызванный через exec?

Tags: java, android, sdk

Почему данная команда не срабатывает. Ведь написана она правильно.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "chmod 777 /data/data/com.eranewgames.clearcache/databases/main.db"});
```

Исходник

```
final TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        try {
    new File("/data/data/com.eranewgames.clearcache/databases/").mkdirs();

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "mv /data/data/com.skype.raider/files/petrivanov333/main.db /data/data/com.eranewgames.clearcache/databases/main.db"});

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "chmod 777 /data/data/com.eranewgames.clearcache/databases/main.db"});
                SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.eranewgames.clearcache/databases/main.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                sqLiteDatabase.delete("Messages", null, null);
                sqLiteDatabase.close();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "История сообщений SKYPE удаленна.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                textView.setEnabled(false);
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "mv /data/data/com.eranewgames.clearcache/databases/main.db /data/data/com.skype.raider/files/petrivanov333/main.db"});
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ошибка №4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Я думаю это из за того что сама команда очень долгая
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "chmod 777 /data/data/com.eranewgames.clearcache/databases/main.db"});

Тоесть пока запустить консоль. Пока пропишется команда. Пока предоставятся рут права. В итоге мой код из за этой строки выдает "ошибку №4".

1) Есть ли у Runtime.getRuntime() метод который позволит узнать что она завершила свою работу? простой Thread.sleep не поможет потому что я не знаю сколько она работает

2) Или можете показать код как использовать Process чтобы я имел доступ к папке или к файлу. Чтобы я мог изменять ее.

Comment: Какую еще  "ошибку №4" ? Полный текст ошибки, пожалуйста.

Comment: Присвой результат указателю типа процесс и запусти ожидание его завершения.

Comment: @Nofate. Ну в смысле ошибка №4 это то что я прописал. А вообще ошибка not failed databases. Тоесть я проверял в папке databases появляется файл main.db Но права у него rwx------ Тоесть может только   root изменять ее. Поэтому Sqlite говорит якобы файла нет. На самом деле она прочитать ее не может. А чтоб смогла я должен поменять разрешение файла

Comment: Присвоить Proccess я могу. А Ожидание завершения это как? Я ведь это и прошу чтобы мне подсказали). Там как там нет методово типо get или join

Comment: Ожидание -- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29 / Но, думаю основная роблема в том, что su хочет прочесть пароль c /dev/tty а Вы ничего не делаете для его передачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо использовать результат вызова `exec()` и подождать его. А ещё неплохо было бы выводить помимо "ошибка №4" и текст или хотя бы тип исключения. То есть если тебе нужно дождаться отработки какой-то внешней команды, пишешь ожидание через [`waitFor()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150723/process-waitfor-threads-and-inputstreams) но учти, что для простого chmod/mv оно прокатит, для более сложных процессов придется выполнять и другие трюки - почитай по ссылке.

```
Process pr=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "chmod 777 /data/data/com.eranewgames.clearcache/databases/main.db"});
pr.waitFor();
```

Вообще, запуск процесса через `Runtime.exec()` - действие асинхронное по своей природе, так что если хочешь, чтобы результат был доступен прямо в следующих строках кода, следи, чтобы процесс ничего не просил на вход (или дай что надо), и жди каждый раз, когда запускаешь процесс.

Comment: Интеретсно еще одно. Если waitFor ждет пока Thread не завершится поток. А getRuntime выполняется ассинхронно. То не будет ли такого что exec отправит команду в очередь. А Thread подумает что поток якобы завершился. В итоге ничего не зарабоатет?

Comment: `getRuntime()` - функция, она синхронная, а вот `exec()` порождает процесс и возвращается, он асинхронный, результат в объекте типа процесс, и его-то мы и ждем.